# FreeRADIUS + AWS NLB Ignoring new connection due to client max_connections (16)

Tags: freeradius, health-check, aws-nlb

I am currently facing an issue while configuring the AWS Network Load Balancer health check in FreeRADIUS. I would appreciate some guidance and assistance regarding this matter.

To provide some context, my FreeRADIUS site configuration looks like this:

```
server aws-nlb {
    client aws-nlb1 {
        ipaddr = 10.0.2.10
        proto = tcp
        secret = "this-will-never-be-used"
    }
    
    client aws-nlb2 {
        ipaddr = 10.0.3.179
        proto = tcp
        secret = "this-will-never-be-used"
    }
    
    listen {
        type = status
        proto = tcp
        ipaddr = *
        port = 8000
    }
    
    authorize {
        reject
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering a problem where the log displays the following message after some time:

```
... new connection request on TCP socket
Ignoring new connection due to client max_connections (16)
```

I'm unsure if this behavior is expected or if there's a way to resolve this issue. I would greatly appreciate any expertise or insights you can provide.

If you have any suggestions, recommendations, or potential solutions, please kindly share them with me. I'm open to exploring alternative approaches or making necessary modifications to the configuration to rectify the problem.

I expected that the "Ignoring new connection due to client max_connections" message not appearing in the logs

Comment: Set the max_connection client definition. Setting it to 0 is unlimited, which is likely unadvised for production. https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/clients.html